# BufferReader howto

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I have a text file that I am reading with `BufferedReader`. It only captures and stores the word *oshane*, but I want *oshane.png* to be read by the buffer. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Name.txt :
`photo:oshane.png`

This is my method:

```java
try {
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int pos = str.indexOf(":");
        String temp = str.substring(pos + 1, str.length());
        if ((str.contains("photo"))) {
            photo = temp;
        }
```

Comment: str does not contain "name".

Comment: Try photo=str; to see the readed line.

Answer (score 0):

Use Split() method instead of indexOf()

```
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     if ((str.contains("photo:"))) {
      name = str.split("\\:")[1];
      }
}
```